# Android activity crashes when populating the listview with data from external databse in the form of JSON

Tags: android, json, listview, navigation-drawer

here is the logcat error in image:

[image: here is the logcat error in image]

with error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.erp.navigationdrawer/com.erp.navigationdrawer.Notices}: java.lang.NullPointerException

This is  my code of main activity which other activity extends to have a navigation drawer now on clicking notices in navigation drawer webservice is called and data comes but activity crashes and shows up:

```
ERROR AT mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer);
    // if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // // on first time display view for first nav item
    // // displayView(0);
    // }
}

public void set(String[] navMenuTitles, TypedArray navMenuIcons) {
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items
    if (navMenuIcons == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < navMenuTitles.length; i++) {
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i]));
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < navMenuTitles.length; i++) {
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i],
                    navMenuIcons.getResourceId(i, -1)));
        }
    }

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    // getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, // nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
            // accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
    // accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

}

private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/***
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    // boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    // menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Courses.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();// finishes the current activity
        break;
    case 1:
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Notices.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
        finish();
        break;
    case 2:
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, Placements.class);
        startActivity(intent3);
        finish();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
}
```

Below is the code for Notices activity that crashes up **AND ITS IS THE ONLY ACTIVITY AMONG NAVIGATION DRAWER TO CRASH:

```
private void loadservice(String url) {

    // Make RESTful webservice call using AsyncHttpClient object

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client.get(url, null, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        // When the response returned by REST has Http response
        // code '200'
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {

            try {
                JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonChild = obj.getJSONObject(i);

                    heading = jsonChild.optString("heading").toString();
                    content = jsonChild.optString("content").toString();
                    date = jsonChild.optString("date".toString());

                    System.out.println(heading + content + date);
                    entity = new NoticeEntity();

                    entity.setNotice_heading(heading);
                    entity.setNotice_content(content);
                    entity.setNotice_date(date);
                    arraylist.add(entity);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println(" Exception raised : " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
    });

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notice_listview);
    NoticeAdapter adapter = new NoticeAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_notice,
            arraylist);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Here is my **NOTICE ADAPTER ** code below:

```
public class NoticeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NoticeEntity> {

    private Context context;

    public NoticeAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
            ArrayList<NoticeEntity> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /* private view holder class */
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView heading;
        TextView content;
        TextView date;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        NoticeEntity entity = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_notice, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.heading = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtvw_notice_heading);
            holder.content = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtvw_notice_content);
            holder.date = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtvw_notice_date);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.heading.setText(entity.getNotice_heading());
        holder.content.setText(entity.getNotice_content());
        holder.date.setText(entity.getNotice_date());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onPostCreate will be executed immediately after onCreate.  You're accessing a member variable called mDrawerToggle in your onPostCreate, but it is not assigned before onPostCreate is called.  It is normal convention to assign all your views to member variables during onCreate immedately after you call setContentView.  In your case, it's being assigned in a method called "set" where I can't see that it's ever being called.

Try moving all the view-related code from `set` into `onCreate`.